# How to customise gradle android test html report

Tags: android, junit, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm developing acceptance tests for an android app. The android gradle plugin generates pretty html report for the tests. Now I want to customise the report, embedding screenshots links into failure test cases, something like this:

[image]

Here is my current solution:

pull screenshots by adb and decorating html report after the report is generated

```
task fetchScreenshots(type: Exec) {  
    executable "adb"
    args "pull", 
        "/sdcard/Robotium-Screenshots/",   
        "${buildDir}/outputs/reports/androidTests/connected/Robotium-Screenshots/"
}

task decoratingAndroidTestsHtmlReport << {
    def screenshots = fileTree("${buildDir}/outputs/reports/androidTests/connected/Robotium-Screenshots")

    screenshots.each { screenshot ->

        def testName = screenshot.name.substring(0, screenshot.name.lastIndexOf("."))
        def testClassName = testClassName(testName)
        def testMethodName = testMethodName(testName)

        def html = file("${buildDir}/outputs/reports/androidTests/connected/${testClassName}.html")
        def patternToFind = "<h3 class=\"failures\">${testMethodName}</h3>"
        def patternToReplace = "${patternToFind}<a href=\"Robotium-Screenshots/${screenshot.name}\">Screenshot</a>"

        replacePatternInFile(html){
            it.replaceAll(patternToFind, patternToReplace)
        }
    }
}

gradle.projectsEvaluated {

    decoratingAndroidTestsHtmlReport.dependsOn(fetchScreenshots)

    connectedAndroidTest {
        finalizedBy decoratingAndroidTestsHtmlReport
    }
}
```

This approach works, but I think it is not the right way to do it. I think it will be much cleaner to modify the html template rather than hacking the html content itself. But I don't find a clue to get started.

Comment: Spoon was a great way to do this - unfortunately there are some problems with 3.x

Comment: I'm in a similar place as you. It's unfortunate that I can't find a hack to save screenshots directly to the test report folder.